How to work with asynchronous methods in Media Foundation?
I'm trying to use IMFMediaSession for simple video playback. The documentation states most of its methods are asynchronous, and I will receive notifications through IMFAsyncCallback when they complete. But it's not clear what happens when multiple asynchronous calls are issued. For example, after I call IMFMediaSession::SetTopology, can I call IMFMediaSession::Start immediately, or do I have to wait for the MESessionTopologySet event?
As another example, the example code in "How to Perform Scrubbing" calls IMFMediaSession::Start immediately after IMFRateControl::SetRate, without waiting for the MESessionRateChanged Event, which would only work if asynchronous requests are completed strictly sequentially in FIFO order. Is that the case?


... what happens when multiple asynchronous calls are issued. For example, after I call IMFMediaSession::SetTopology, can I call IMFMediaSession::Start immediately ...

You cannot start an unresolved (= not yet created) topology, can you?
The asynchronicity idea is about (1) not blocking the caller calls (2) separating bigger tasks into smaller work items executed serially and/or in parallel as needed.
In most cases you are supposed to make calls and catch completion as asynchronous handlers. Implementations will not execute your requests immediately: they will post work items on work queues internally, with possibly multiple work items to do, and then in the end on completion you would have a notification. But sometimes you can make a few calls in a row immediately as they are just queued internally for sequential execution. In your rate changing example changed rate is not blocking the topology to start/stop. But unresolved topology would be an obstacle.

I can't start an unresolved topology, but I can queue a request to start it after it's resolved - if the framework supports such sequential queuing model. According to your description there is no way in general to determine if it's safe to issue multiple asynchronous calls. As another example, to perform scrubbing, I need to SetRate(0.f) -> Start() potentially multiple times -> Pause() -> SetRate(1.f) ->Start(). In this case the topology changes states, would it still be safe to do all this without waiting for completion?

You normally have to respond to asynchronous completions to maximal extent. Internally in most cases work item queues are serialized, and it's possibly to "append" the requests, but this implementation detail is hidden and you don't really know how exactly this is handled. On the other hand this design is still safe in handling requests received out of context. Your too early early request would probably be ignored without damage to the state of the session, and would rather create a trouble for you in matching the state of the player, rather than breaking the session itself.

What do you mean by responding to maximal extent, do I have to keep a queue of commands and only issue the next one when I receive the completion notification from the previous one? And what would be a sensible way to keep track of the state of the player, seeing that there is an inherent delay to state updates?

I mean that I recommend to serialize your actions with asynchronous completions rather than queuing requests without knowing how these new requests overlapping completions of previous are handled by the pipeline. Error handling might be complicated because those requests might be again posted to worker threads, fail there, and then again error reporting and completion will be another internal asynchronous requests, and then you end with random thread triggering some error without giving you sufficient information what happened. Also you won't have consistency with these errors.

Going by this line of reasoning, the MSDN scrubbing example is wrong, right? It calls Start() without waiting for rate change completion. So say a session is currently paused and SetRate() fails asynchronously. The example code inadvertently starts the session because it doesn't wait to see if SetRate() eventually succeeds or not. Does this mean the only robust way to interact with media session is to maintain my own queue of asynchronous method calls and never overlap them? That sounds terribly complex to work with.

I have not looked at this particular sample, but (1) MSDN samples are not perfect (2) yes, I would not want SetRate and Play overlap, esp. in sample code. They might do it because they assume that rate change won't fail, or won't fail fatally.
